# Why does Resolve-DnsName behave differently on different computers?

Tags: powershell, dns

The `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet seems to return different things depending on where I run it.

If I run `(Resolve-DnsName redacted.mydomain.com).IP4Address` on computer1 I get a single IP address, and on computer2 I get a list of two (the same address twice).

I can't solve this by always running `(Resolve-DnsName redacted.mydomain.com).IP4Address[0]` because that will give me only the first number of the address on computer1.

Both computers are running powershell version `5.1.19041.1023` and `Resolve-DnsName` version `1.0.0.0`.

Comment: Probably a load balancer or different DNS servers on both computers. Try `'208.67.222.222','1.1.1.1','8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4','199.85.126.10' | %{(Resolve-DnsName google.com -Server $_ -Type A).IpAddress}`, you're likely to see different IPs for google.

Comment: Wait, I missed the ***(the same address twice)***, is that so? Are you sure it's exactly the same IP?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, exactly the same IP. Some more context, the IP I'm resolving is that of an RDS instance. And running `Resolve-DnsName` against some other servers return only one IP address, as expected.

Comment: Same DNS servers on both computers?

Comment: Not sure, as the computers point to the router for DNS. I don't have access to these routers.

Comment: Instead of [0] use | select-object -first 1 as a work around

Comment: It honestly sounds like a DNS issue itself, and not on the client side. Could be that the DHCP Server leased 2 different IPs to the same computer name and the DNS record isn't properly talking to the DHCP. I would get in touch with your sys admins

Comment: Thanks Doug Maurer, that will do as a solution